# Xcode 11 SwiftUI preview "communication with the app was interrupted"

Tags: swiftui, xcode11

I am following the [SwiftUI watchOS tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-a-watchos-app) but I keep getting the following error when trying to preview `WatchMapView` in Section 4 Step 6:

> WatchLandmarks.app crashed: communication with the app was interrupted

The error starts to occur only after adding this in `WatchLandmarkDetail`:

```swift
WatchMapView(landmark: self.landmark)
    .scaledToFit()
    .padding()
```

The `WatchMapView` code is as follows

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct WatchMapView: WKInterfaceObjectRepresentable {        
    var landmark: Landmark

    func makeWKInterfaceObject(context: WKInterfaceObjectRepresentableContext<WatchMapView>) -> WKInterfaceMap {
        return WKInterfaceMap()
    }

    func updateWKInterfaceObject(_ map: WKInterfaceMap, context: WKInterfaceObjectRepresentableContext<WatchMapView>) {

        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.02,
            longitudeDelta: 0.02)

        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(
            center: landmark.locationCoordinate,
            span: span)

        map.setRegion(region)
    }        
}

struct WatchMapView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        WatchMapView(landmark: UserData().landmarks[0])
         .previewDevice("Apple Watch Series 5 - 44mm")
    }
}
```

Comment: Seeing the same thing — using Xcode 11.2.1 (11B500). I'd blame this on yet another bug with SwiftUI / Xcode, as other tutorial sections revealed other random problems like this.